Help Identify SMD Part Marking ATPJ
It's a 6-pin SOT with marking "|ATPJ".
My guess is it's SOT-363 but I'm not entirely sure.
Can you identify the actual part number for this.


It's a MPS MP6907GJ fast turn-off flyback synchronous rectifier.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thanks! That helps a lot.

could you tell me which steps did you take to narrow down the search? I have another 5 pin IC from the same manufacturer with marking |APKP but again I can't find the part number.

@Farah https://www.google.com/search?q=MPS%20%22APK:%20Product%20Code%22
